# Proof or Counterexample of Claim for Homeomorphism of Disjoint Unions

Tags: general-topology

Let $\{X_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in A}$ be a disjoint family of sets, where each $X_\alpha\cong X$ (homeomorphic) for an arbitrary topological space $X$. Define a topology on $\bigcup_{\alpha\in A}X_\alpha$ by
$$\tau_\cup:=\left\{U\subseteq\bigcup_{\alpha\in A}X_\alpha\colon \forall\alpha\in A, U\cap X_\alpha\in\tau_\alpha\right\},$$
where $\tau_\alpha$ is the subspace topology on $X_\alpha$ -- that is, a set is open in $\bigcup_{\alpha\in A}X_\alpha$ iff it is open in $X_\alpha$. Is it true that
$$\bigsqcup_{\alpha\in A}X_\alpha\cong \bigcup_{\alpha\in A}(X\times\{\alpha\})=X\times A$$
under this topology?

I know that if $X_\alpha\cong X$, then it should also be true that $X_\alpha\cong X\times\{\alpha\}$, but I'm not sure that it's true for unions, even if disjoint. If it's in general false, are there conditions under which it holds?

**Edit:** $A$ is also an arbitrary topological space.

Comment: $A$ should be given the discrete topology for this to hold, see the given answer. It won't work for any $A$ (which is just an index set originally, but is given this discrete topology to set up a homeomorphism with $X \times A$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $u_\alpha : X_\alpha \to X$ be a homeomorphism for each $\alpha\in A$. If you endow $A$ with the discrete topology, then the mapping

$$F: \bigsqcup_{\alpha\in A}X_\alpha \to X\times A, \ \ F(x_\alpha) = (u_\alpha (x_\alpha), \alpha)$$
for all $x_\alpha \in X_\alpha$ is a homeomorphism: Every open set $U$ in $X\times A$ can be given by a union of open sets

$$ U = \bigcup_{\alpha \in A} U_\alpha, $$
where $U_\alpha = U\cap (X\times \{\alpha\})$. Then
$$ F^{-1} (U) = \bigcup _{\alpha\in A} u_\alpha^{-1} (U_\alpha)$$
is open. Thus $F$ is continuous. Similarly one checks that
$$ F^{-1} : X\times A \to \bigsqcup_{\alpha\in A}X_\alpha, \ \ F^{-1}(x,\alpha) = u^{-1}_\alpha (x)$$
is continuous. Thus $F$ is a homeomorphism.